# Setting Tag Using Google Cloud Api

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to set Tag for a server with google api. But for some reason its not setting the tag and its not giving back any error.
I use the example from https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/setTags

I also tried calling the same method using live api requests which also gives me 200 but the tag is not getting set.[Api Live Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG0Cj.png)

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out. We need to pass "fingerprint" along with the tag body to make changes to the metadata.

I think if fingerprint was missing, the response should not be 200?